# how remove sublists from a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list, I wanna make a new list where non of items are a sub list of others.

```
all_clusters=[['A','B','C'],['C','B'],['T','A'],['A']]
```

the second element is the subset of the first one so I wanna remove it. same 4 and 1.

output:

```
all_clusters=[['A','B','C'],['T','A']]
```

I did the following:

```
 ind=[]
for s,i in enumerate(all_clusters):
    for r,j in enumerate(all_clusters):
        if i!=j:
            if all(j[k] in i for k in range(len(j))):
                ind.append([s,r])
```

now I wanna remove all all_clusters[p[0]] for p in ind.

how I can do that? `all_clusters.remove()` dosn't work for indices. is there a better way?

Comment: ```all_clusters.pop(index)``` works. Use ```.pop()``` for indices instead of ```.remove()```

Comment: Sidenote: this is simpler: `if i != j and all(x in i for x in j):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set().issubset()`

Example

```py
new_lst = [x for x in all_clusters if not any(set(x).issubset(y) for y in all_clusters if y!=x)]
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['T', 'A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `del all_clusters[index]`, but because that would change the later indexes, you'd have to do it in reverse.

It's easier to use a comprehension to filter out the ones you don't want:

```
avoid = {duplicate for original, duplicate in ind}
result = [cluster for i, cluster in enumerate(all_clusters) if i not in avoid]
print(result)  # -> [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['T', 'A']]
```

If you specifically want to overwrite `all_clusters`, you can use a full-slice assignment like this:

```
all_clusters[:] = result
```